# How to select row of a table when user taps on it using tap event of jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a table

```
<table>
    <tr> Row 1 </tr>
    <tr> Row 2 </tr>
    <tr> Row 3 </tr>
</table>
```

Now I need to write a code such that **when I select one or more row by tapping on my tablet, proceed button should be enabled else it should be disabled**. I am new to jQuery so not able to put this in code.

Comment: where's the proceed button i dont see it in your code

Comment: Your HTML is invalid; text cannot appear in a `<tr>` unless it's wrapped in either `<th>` or `<td>` elements; and if you're new? Then you should probably start by researching (Google relevant-seeming phrases such as 'select element on tap jQuery') and then make an attempt. Being new doesn't exempt you from making an effort, it requires you to demonstrate that you have understanding of, at the very least, the broad strokes (even if only in pseudo-code) of the answer and what you want to do.

Comment: @bondythegreat i thought you will assume it to be there.. anyways it is below the table. <button id="proceedBtn"> Proceed </button>. :)

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for the suggestion mate. I posted the question after looking for it over the web and also tried few codes which did not work out. I am also aware that we need to wrap the text in <td>. Just because I had less time to complete my task i thought I would use this forum. And yes I am new to all this UI thing :) I hope now you will not have any hesitation in answering my question, if you know the answer. But I totally agree that we need make effort :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table has id table and the button that should be enabled has id button:

```
  $( "#table tr" ).bind( "tap", tapHandler );

    function tapHandler( event ){

          $( event.target ).toggleClass( "tapped" );
         if($(".tapped").size() > 0)
           $("#button").attr("disabled", false);
       else $("#button").attr("disabled", true);


      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplest solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

example html markup (you must nest `td` elements within `tr`, you can't insert a text directly under a `tr`):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="Foo" class="btn" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('table tr').bind('touchend', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected'))
            $(this).find('.btn').removeAttr('disabled');
        else
            $(this).find('.btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

see a jsFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/up5wf2o4/

- note: i used the `touchend` event since you might not have the `tap` event supported, unless you're using jQuery mobile or any other supporting library. if so, go ahead and replace `touchend` with `tap`.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your table with some modifications (I added TD elements):

```
<table> 
    <tr data-row="row 1"><td> Row 1 </td></tr> 
    <tr data-row="row 2"><td> Row 2 </td></tr> 
    <tr data-row="row 3"><td> Row 3 </td></tr> 
</table>
```

Event handling:

```
  $( "table tr" ).bind( "tap", tapHandler );

  function tapHandler( event ){
      var dataRow = $( this ).attr("data-row");
      alert( dataRow);
  }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/uq1gcp83/)